# {AWS LAMBDA FUNCTION} Unable to import module 'index': urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with OpenSSL

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openai-api

I am experiencing an issue with an AWS Lambda function that is written in Python 3.8. The error I'm encountering is as follows:

```
Unable to import module 'index': urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with OpenSSL
```

The pipfile in my lambda function looks something like below:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
src = {editable = true, path = "./src"}
openai = "*"
urllib3 = "1.26.6"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

The index.py file has the following import and the error that I am receiving seems to be due to openai import.

```
import json
import boto3
import openai
import os
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
```

To provide some context, my function is running in a virtual environment (venv), also set to Python 3.8.

Here are some troubleshooting steps that I have already attempted:

Downgrading the urllib3 version in the venv environment.
Upgrading the Python version in the venv.
However, neither of these steps resolved the issue. I am still receiving the same error regarding the OpenSSL version that the 'ssl' module is compiled with.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Downgrading the urllib3 version.Upgrading the Python version in the venv. However, neither of these steps resolved the issue. I am still receiving the same error regarding the OpenSSL version that the 'ssl' module is compiled with.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the 'ssl' module in your Python environment is compiled with an older version of OpenSSL that is not compatible with urllib3 v2.0, which you are using in your AWS Lambda function. To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

Update the OpenSSL version in your Python environment:

You mentioned that you are using a virtual environment (venv). Make sure that the OpenSSL version in your venv is up to date. You can try updating OpenSSL by upgrading your Python version or by updating OpenSSL directly.

Use a compatible version of urllib3:

The error message indicates that urllib3 v2.0 is causing the issue. You can try using a compatible version of urllib3 that works with your current OpenSSL version. Modify your pipfile to specify an older version of urllib3, such as version 1.26.6, which you were previously using.

```
[packages]
src = {editablCheck the Lambda environment:
urllib3 = "==1.26.6"
```

Double-check that the AWS Lambda environment you are using supports the required OpenSSL version for urllib3 v2.0. If the environment does not have the necessary OpenSSL version, you may need to consider using a different environment or exploring other alternatives.

Verify Lambda deployment package:

Ensure that you are packaging and deploying your Lambda function correctly with the updated dependencies. Confirm that the deployed package includes the correct versions of urllib3 and other required libraries.

Test locally:

Before deploying the function to AWS Lambda, test it locally within your virtual environment. Ensure that all the required libraries and dependencies are working as expected without any OpenSSL-related issues.

If none of the above steps resolve the issue, you might consider reaching out to the AWS support team for further assistance or providing more specific details about your environment, including the exact versions of Python, OpenSSL, and any other relevant libraries you are using.e = true, path = "./src"}

Comment: Hey, yeah apparently I ended up creating a lambda function using serverless, and downgrading the urllib on both boto3 and openai worked. I really appreciate your response;Thanks.